# Finding correlation between cryptocurrency data

Tags: python, pandas, analytics, bitcoin, ethereum

I am having one dataset about cryptocurrency. the columns of dataset are as follows :
1. name of currency
2. date
3. high
4. low
5. close
6. open
7. volume
8. marketcap

I want to find the correlation between high of two currencies. For example Correlation between High of Bitcoin and Ethereum. How it can be done in pandas ?

Answer (score 2):

I would try using [.corr()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) to calculate the correlation. Maybe try filtering your table into two subset tables (one for Bitcoin and one for Ethereum).

```
df1 = Core_Table[Core_Table['name of currency'] == 'Bitcoin']
df2 = Core_Table[Core_Table['name of currency'] == 'Ethereum']
```

Now calculate the correlation of the highs.

```
df1['high'].corr(df2['high'])
```